# STM32F103 reset button does not work

Tags: ethernet, reset, stm32f10x, stm32f103c8t6

I am working project, using `STM32F103C8T6` and `W5500` Ethernet module. My project is something like network relay. My problem is that the `STM32F103` can not boot up after pressing reset button when the  `BOOT0` jumper is on the position 0. But when I am pressing the reset button when the `BOOT0` jumper is on the position 1, it resets successful, and removing old program from `STM board`. I' am using `UDP` to send and receive data over network connection.

Library I'm using for `Ehternet module W5500`
[Ethernet_STM](https://github.com/Serasidis/Ethernet_STM)

Ethernet module:
[W5500 Ethernet module](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/W5500-Ethernet-network-module-hardware-TCP-IP-51-STM32-microcontroller-program-over-W5100/32763613497.html)

STM board I'm usng:
[STM32F103C8T6](https://www.amazon.in/xcluma-STM32F103C8T6-Minimum-System-Development/dp/B072TD7BJ3)

My sketch:

```
#include <SPI.h>         // needed for Arduino versions later than 0018
#include <Ethernet_STM.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>         // UDP library from: bjoern@cs.stanford.edu 12/30/2008
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <EmonLib.h>

//write(0x00, 0x05, 128); // Software reset the W5500 chip
//line 333 in w5500.h    __SOCKET_REGISTER16(SnRX_WR,    0x002A)      // RX Write Pointer (supported?)


#if defined(WIZ550io_WITH_MACADDRESS) // Use assigned MAC address of WIZ550io
;
#else
byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
#endif
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 200);
IPAddress mydns(192,168,0,1);
unsigned int localPort = 8888;      // local port to listen on


char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE]; //buffer to hold incoming packet,


EthernetUDP Udp;
EnergyMonitor enMonitor0, enMonitor1;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 16, 2);

const int acVoltage0 = PA0;
const int acVoltage1 = PA1;
const int analogIn = PA3;
const int currentPin = PA2;
const int statusPin = PC13;
const int relay1 = PB0;
const int relay2 = PB1;
const int relay3 = PB3;
const int relay4 = PB4;
const float r_divider = 0.048122;
double V_AC0, V_AC1, Amps, voltageDC;
bool auth = false;
bool entering = false;
bool pchange = false;
char *key = "asdf";

void setup()
{
#if defined(WIZ550io_WITH_MACADDRESS)
  Ethernet.begin(ip);
#else
  Ethernet.begin(mac,ip, mydns);
#endif  
  Udp.begin(localPort);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("STARTED");
  disableDebugPorts();
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
  pinMode(PB11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(statusPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(analogIn, INPUT_ANALOG);
  pinMode(currentPin, INPUT_ANALOG);
  digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
  enMonitor0.voltage(acVoltage0, 227, 1.7);
  enMonitor1.voltage(acVoltage1, 227, 1.7);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(" -++=EDISON=++-  ");
  Serial.println("END of setup");
  //nvic_sys_reset();   //Reset STM32F103C
}



double measureVoltage_AC0()
{
  double V_AC;
  enMonitor0.calcVI(200, 2000);
  V_AC = enMonitor0.Vrms * 1.51;
  return V_AC;
}

double measureVoltage_AC1()
{
  double V_AC;
  enMonitor1.calcVI(200, 2000);
  V_AC = enMonitor1.Vrms * 1.51;
  return V_AC;
}

double measureVoltage_DC()
{
  uint16_t adcin;
  double voltage;
  adcin = analogRead(analogIn);
  voltage = 3.3 / 4095 * adcin;
  voltage = voltage * 20;
  return voltage;
}

double measureCurrent()
{
  uint16_t RawValue = 0;
  double Voltage = 0;
  double Amps = 0;
  RawValue = analogRead(currentPin);
  Voltage = (RawValue / 4095.0) * 5000; // Gets you mV
  Amps = ((Voltage - 600) / 60);
  if (RawValue < 50)  Amps = 0.0;
  return Amps;
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("loop");
  digitalWrite(PB11, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(PB11, HIGH);
  delay(100);
main:
  Serial.println("mAIN");
  V_AC0 = measureVoltage_AC0();
  V_AC1 = measureVoltage_AC1();
  voltageDC = measureVoltage_DC();
  Amps = measureCurrent();
  Serial.println("lcd.printing");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(V_AC0);
  lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
  lcd.print("V");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(V_AC1);
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print("V");
  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
  lcd.print(voltageDC);
  lcd.setCursor(15, 0);
  lcd.print("V");
  lcd.setCursor(10, 1);
  lcd.print(Amps);
  lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
  lcd.print("A");
  Serial.println(" end lcd.printing");
  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  Serial.println(packetSize);
  if (packetSize)
  {
    IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    if (auth == false && entering == false)
    {
      Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
      Udp.write("Please Enter KEY");
      Udp.endPacket();
      entering = true;
    }
    else if (!auth && entering)
    {
      if (strstr(packetBuffer, key))
      {
        auth = true;
        entering = false;
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("Auth OK");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
    }
    else if (auth)
    {
      if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R1=ON"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K1 turned ON");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R1=OFF"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K1 turned OFF");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R2=ON"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K2 turned ON");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R2=OFF"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K2 turned OFF");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R3=ON"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K3 turned ON");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R3=OFF"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K3 turned OFF");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R4=ON"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K4 turned ON");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "R4=OFF"))
      {
        digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("K4 turned OFF");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "MEASURES"))
      {
        char ac1[10], ac2[10], dc[10], amps[10];
        dtostrf(V_AC0, 4, 2, ac1);
        dtostrf(V_AC1, 4, 2, ac2);
        dtostrf(voltageDC, 4, 2, dc);
        dtostrf(Amps, 4, 2, amps);
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("VAC1 = ");
        Udp.write(ac1);
        Udp.write(" ");
        Udp.write("VAC2 = ");
        Udp.write(ac2);
        Udp.write(" ");
        Udp.write("VDC = ");
        Udp.write(dc);
        Udp.write(" ");
        Udp.write("A = ");
        Udp.write(amps);
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "CHPASS"))
      {
        pchange = true;
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("Enter new KEY");
        Udp.endPacket();
        while (pchange)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
          {
            packetBuffer[i] = 0;
          }
          int tmp = Udp.parsePacket();
          if (tmp)
          {
            Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
            int len = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
              if (packetBuffer[i] > 0)
                len++;
            }
            Serial.println(len);
            if (len != 4)
            {
              Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
              Udp.write("Only 4 digit");
              Udp.endPacket();
            }
            else
            {
              key = packetBuffer;
              Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
              Udp.write("New KEY is: ");
              Udp.write(key);
              Udp.endPacket();
              pchange = false;
              goto main;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "RESTART"))
      {
        nvic_sys_reset();
      }
      else if (strstr(packetBuffer, "LOGOUT"))
      {
        auth = false;
        entering = false;
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write("Log out OK");
        Udp.endPacket();
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
      {
        packetBuffer[i] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

In my opinion this problem causes from the ethernet library, because when I comment the lines which contains the declaration of the objects which is members of this library, the reset function works good.

Any ideas or sulitions will be so good. :)

Comment: Do you understand what the boot mode setting does, and why only one value would work?  Though the required state is low, opposite of your seeming description unless that is a description of a physical position rather than a logical value.

Answer (score 4):

The `BOOT0` pin on the "[*Blue Pill*](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Blue_Pill)" doesn't have any shared functionality, so I'd be very surprised if the Ethernet module is having any effect.

The `BOOTn` pins have special meaning at reset, and the reference manual outlines how they are used. Look at Section 3.4, Table 9:

[image: BOOTn Config]

- `BOOT0 = 0` - the STM32 will boot from Flash Memory
- `BOOT0 = 1` and `BOOT1 = 0` - the STM32 will boot from "*System Memory*" (i.e: the ROM bootloader)
- `BOOT0 = 1` and `BOOT1 = 1` - the STM32 will boot from embedded SRAM

This contradicts what you're observing, so the first things I'd query are:

- Did you put your binary into the STM32's flash memory, or did you load it into RAM?
- How are you loading your binary? STLink?
- The "[*Blue Pill*](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Blue_Pill)" that you're using has both `BOOT0` and `BOOT1` on that 6-pin header, they should both be set to 0 - on the boards I have that is "*close to the Micro USB connector*", as pictured below.

[image: Blue Pill Boot Mode]